# How to access Twitter screenname, avatar when autopublish has been turned off

Tags: twitter, meteor

In Meteor, I believe ordinarily you can get the screenname of a twitter user after they've logged in with `{{services.twitter.screenName}}`.

However with autopublish turned off the only thing that seems to be available is `{{currentUser.profile.name}}` (which returns their 'full name' i.e. `Kevin Rose`, not `krose`).

How would I go about getting the screenname or avatar from a user that has logged in with Twitter, if autopublish has been removed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to set up a publish record on the server to determine what information you're going to send to the client, and then subscribe to it in a client-side startup function (or better still, iron-router).

```
Meteor.publish("userData", function () {
return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId},
    {fields: {'services.twitter': 1}});
});
```

That will provide the services field for the logged in user in `Meteor.user()` once that client has subscribed to `"userData"` in addition to the fields that are automatically supplied.

Comment: This isn't a good idea, you should publish `services.twitter` but not services. This way you expose all the loginTokens under the `resume` set. Additionally as the user uses the app more the size builds up significantly and it can decrease the loading time.

Comment: Agreed, answer amended.

Answer (score 2):

You need to manually publish / subscribe your data. By default, only `emails`, `username` and `profile` fields are published for `Meteor.users` collection ([see the docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_user)). So you need to publish others:

```
Meteor.publish('userData', function() {
    if(!this.userId) return null;
    return Meteor.users.find(this.userId, {fields: {
        services: 1,
        ...
    }});
});
```

After that, subscribe to this channel on the client:

```
Deps.autorun(function() {
    Meteor.subscribe('userData');
});
```

Comment: Thank you. This and @richsliv's answer are both great. They both arrived at exactly the same time, too (to the minute). I hope you don't mind, but I accepted richsliv's simply because he has the lower reputation (after being advised to do so on Twitter).